# Why is my NextJS Image component not converting images to webp?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, image, next.js, webp

Using Next version 12.3.2.

I have a custom component ImagewithFallback setup in my NextJS application. For some reason, it is not loading images as webp, but rather jpg. I have tried to remove the custom loader as the default loader uses the next image optimisation api, but then I get a 500 sever error. The images are coming from my mongodb database which is running on another port. On vercel they are being sent from an api. Below is my entire custom image component.

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import Image from "next/image";
import PropTypes from "prop-types";

const ImageWithFallback = (props) => {
  const { src, fallbackSrc, width, height, objectFit, presrc, ...rest } = props;
  const [imgSrc, setImgSrc] = useState(src);

  // update the image src if a new src is supplied. e.g. first src is undefined but then later its defined
  // without this the fallback image will always be selected if the initial component render has a bad src
  useEffect(() => {
    if (!src || src.endsWith("null") || src.endsWith("undefined")) {
      setImgSrc(fallbackSrc);
    } else if (src !== imgSrc) {
      setImgSrc(src);
    }
  }, [src]);

  const loader = ({ src, width, quality }) => {
    return `${src}?w=${width}&q=${quality || 75}`;
  };

  return (
    <Image
      {...rest}
      width={width}
      
      height={height}
      src={imgSrc}
      objectFit={objectFit}
      onError={() => {
        setImgSrc(fallbackSrc);
      }}
    />
  );
};

ImageWithFallback.propTypes = {
  width: PropTypes.oneOfType([PropTypes.string, PropTypes.number]),
  height: PropTypes.oneOfType([PropTypes.string, PropTypes.number]),
  src: PropTypes.string,
  fallbackSrc: PropTypes.string,
  objectFit: PropTypes.string,
};

ImageWithFallback.defaultProps = {
  fallbackSrc: "/images/placeholder.gif",
};

export default ImageWithFallback;
```

For my next.config.js I have set up the domain names for localhost as such

```
  images: {
    domains: ['localhost'],
  },
```

How can I make it so images sent from my localhost db server are converted into webp?

Answer (score 1):

You should use following config

```
  images: {
    domains: ['http://localhost:3000'],
  },
```

Comment: That is not working, the image is still falling back to the placeholder. For reference this is the request url "http://localhost:4000/_next/image?url=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A3000%2Fassets%2Ffiles%2FMedia%2F7aBtj9f7v9hc9gZy9%2Fmedium%2F62825prx818xlfwpair.jpg&w=256&q=75"

Answer (score 0):

this because you added unoptimied: true to next.config file

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/35667760)